# Before Delete Trigger, Need to Delete Linked Record, getting "De-reference Null Object" Error

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger, delete

I'm new to Apex and code. I have 2 objects that are linked to each other 1 to 1. There is a lookup to the other record on each record.

I'm writing a trigger that, when record A is deleted, record B is also deleted.

Here's my code:

```
trigger TateTimeEntryNewTrigger on Time_Entry_New__c (before delete) {
List<Id> idsToQuery = new List<Id>{};
for(Time_Entry_New__c ten : Trigger.new) {
    idsToQuery.add(ten.Id);
}

SVMXC__Service_Order_Line__c[] wdsToDelete = [SELECT Id FROM SVMXC__Service_Order_Line__c WHERE Time_Entry_New__c.Id IN :idsToQuery];

delete wdsToDelete;}
```

When I delete record A (Time_Entry_New), I get this error:

> System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object: Trigger.TateTimeEntryNewTrigger: line 3, column 1"

I of course found this code from other examples. I'm thinking it's not necessary to have a list since it's always 1 record? Any thoughts on fixing the error and cleaning up the code will be very appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is happening because `Trigger.new` is not available on `before delete` context. You'll want to use `Trigger.old` instead.

Check this document about [**Trigger Context Variables**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm).

Comment: That did it, thank you! Changing that also uncovered a second problem that my dot notation needed to be Time_Entry_New__r.Id.

Comment: Actually you can just use `Time_Entry_New__c`. The relationship field ended in `__c` is interpreted as an Id. `__r.Id` also works, but it isn't optimal (because you are referring to the object's relationship data instead of the object's data itself).